# Banning space, is there place for more banned champs?

Tags: league-of-legends

[image]

It seems there space for more than 3 banned champions? (seems there is place for 5). So is there ways to have more than 3 banned champions on your game or the box is big like that only because there's enough space for a box that big?

Comment: It looks like there could be room for 10 if two columns are used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently are no ways to get more banns, but Riot added 1 bann (the 3rd for every side) recently, and they are thinking about adding more banns, simply cause the number of champs is growing every 2 weeks, so the number of banns has to grow from time to time as well.

Answer (score 0):

The boxes are that big because there is enough space for them to be that big.
Currently there's no sign that Riot plan on adding more bans to the pick/ban phase.

However as you might have noticed following ggClassics the players "ban" a champion in the lobby by typing out their name. This makes them "have 4 bans".